# Суть FIT (Firmware Interface Table) таблицы

Tags: bios, uefi

В Sec фазе UEFI находится модуль с сигнатурой *FIT*. После стандартного заголовка у него идут какие то данные, похожие на смещения элементов. Я дошел до мысли что это указатели на область защищенной загрузки, но не могу связать воедино всю картину Processor Abstraction Layer(PAL) и System Abstraction Layer(SAL) и как это связано с FIT таблицей. Буду очень благодарен  за любую помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вдруг пригодится.

Сама таблица состоит из двух элементов:

- заголовка (`header`)
- и одной или более записей (`entry`).

Каждая запись (`entry`) таблицы указывает на область памяти, в которой содержится прошивка для того или иного элемента материнской платы.
Варианты прошивки следующие:

- `FIT_HEADER`
- `MICROCODE_UPDATE`
- `BG_ACM`
- `BIOS_INIT`
- `TPM_POLICY`
- `BIOS_POLICY`
- `TXT_POLICY`
- `BG_KEYM`
- `BG_IBBM`

Как не трудно догадаться, она нужна для того, чтобы компоненты ПО имели возможность находить обновления для себя любимых в целом образе. Таблица ищется через указатель, который записан по фиксированному адресу `FFFF FFC0`.

Comment: В вопросе указано о какой таблице идёт речь, но в ответе тоже не плохо  бы упомянуть её. Воспользуйтесь кнопкой [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/655621/edit).